# How can I change item->quantity in rule (Commerce Kickstart)

Tags: commerce, rules

I would like to evaluate line_item -> quantity before line_item is saved.

I've created a rule firing on "before line item saved" event.

I've added 2 actions:

1. Action `variable_add` (evaluating desired quantity of line item)
2. Action `data_set`. Setting data to commerce-line-item:quantity from variable, created in the first action

I'm always getting `Rules evaluating log`. This is an excerpt:

> 0 ms Rule Evaluate quantity fires.
>
> 0.497 ms Evaluating the action variable_add. [edit]
>
> 0.736 ms Added the provided variable variable_added of type decimal [edit]
>
> 1.968 ms Evaluating the action data_set. [edit]
>      69.962 ****ms **Unable to modify data "commerce-line-item:quantity": Invalid      data value*** given. Be
>   sure it matches the required data type and format*.
>
> 72.107 ms Unable to evaluate action data_set. [edit]**
>
> 72.286 ms Rule Evaluating quantity has fired.

How to fix this error?

May I use substitutions (e.g. `[commerce-line-item:quantity]` etc) in PHP evaluation in 1, 2 actions? May I call functions (e.g. `drupal_set_message()` etc)?

Comment: Use the "set message" action under the 'System' section of actions and output the value of the variable to make sure it's an integer!  That should help with troubleshooting...